# Adaptive Cards on MS Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, botpress

I have created a bot with Botpress and connected it to MS Teams via Azure. I would now like to send an adaptive card in Teams. I found out that you can send an adaptive card in teams like this: https://github.com/botpress/solutions/blob/master/custom%20solutions/Send%20adaptive%20cards%20using%20teams/actions/sendAdaptativeCard.js.
My problem now is that I don't get any user inputs back, only objects which Botpress can't read. I have also already opened a discussion in the Botpress forum. See here: https://github.com/botpress/botpress/discussions/12600 Unfortunately, I'm getting nowhere on my own and can't get an answer. Does anyone here have an idea how I can read the user inputs from an Adaptive card in Botpress?
I am new to chatbots and the Microsoft documentation is very detailed but also very confusing. I would be very grateful for any help.

Best regards
Eva

Answer (score 1):

I tired the code below using  adaptive cards in MS Teams bot.

- Thanks for the [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-bot?tabs=vscode,viscode) @[Microsoft Developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards)

**Sample Javascript code**:-

```js
const  card = {
"$schema":  "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version":  "1.4",
"type":  "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
{
"type":  "TextBlock",
"text":  "Hello, world!",
"size":  "large"
}
]
};
const  message = {
type:  "message",
text:  "Here's an adaptive card:",
attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)]
};
await  context.sendActivity(message);
break;
```

- The other way to implement adaptive cards is creating a Json file .

[image]

- Call it in [Reference file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gbzZ.png) and implement the [logic](https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/).

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Reference :

- [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots)

Comment: thanks @Sampath for your help. i tried this, but since i work with botpress it doesn't work that way unfortunately.